# Sliding Background Images with controls

Tags: css, background, scroll, fullscreen

I am trying to build a website which has its background images scroll with left and right controls. Where can I find tutorials to do that?

Comment: Be more specific, could not understand your question. We are not here to find you tutorials. Tell us what you have already tried and we will help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CoinSlider... see this link for tutorials and demo:

http://workshop.rs/2010/04/coin-slider-image-slider-with-unique-effects/

Also see supersized jQuery plugin [full screen slideshow]

http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

OR look here for 100 Qjuery sliders, choose the one that will suit your requirement:

http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/100-jquery-sliders-part1/#.T-YKgRdo2_4

Answer (score 0):

I've used this one in the past and it's worked great. It's uses a fade transition, but I'm sure there are ways to hack it to do slide transitions.

http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/advanced_jquery_background_image_slideshow.html